# Prepend date to filename in powershell if the file does not start with a date already

Tags: date, powershell, conditional-statements, prepend

Using powershell, I'd like to prepend the creation date of a number of files, but only if the filenames do not already start with the date. For other files, the code should skip them.

I've successfully used the following command to prepend dates, but I'd like to make it conditional on the filename not starting with any date format (or perhaps, any digits at all).

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {(Get-Date $_.CreationTime -Format "yyyy-MM-dd ")+ $_.BaseName+$_.Extension}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to match a pattern. I'm not the best with regex but found the following regex elsewhere for matching a date in the format you specified. I just took your existing code and inserted a `Where-Object` to filter out files that already match the pattern.

```
    $regex = [regex] '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
    Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {!($_.Name -match $regex)} | Rename-Item -NewName {(Get-Date $_.CreationTime -Format "yyyy-MM-dd ")+ $_.BaseName+$_.Extension}
```

Comment: The Where-Object command is a really useful start. Is there a way to match it on the file name *starting* with a digit?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not the best at regex. I edited the regex to include an anchor "^" which basically will only match the pattern if it is at the beginning of the filename. The new regex is `'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`

Comment: I figured it out. `Get-ChildItem –File -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.Name –match "^\d) } | Rename-Item -NewName {(Get-Date $_.CreationTime -Format "yyyy-MM-dd ")+ $_.BaseName+$_.Extension}`

Comment: Instead of `!` and `-match` you could use the simpler `-notmatch`. More cryptic but shorter is `gci -fil -rec|? name -notm '^\d'|...`